# Do I need to create a endpoint to use Elastic Load Balancer on my VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, vpc

I'm creating a VPC to host a web app at AWS, and I want to use load balancers. Do I need to create a endpoint for elb like I have to s3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confusing AWS uses 'endpoint' to refer to a couple of different things. Judging by your question are you referring to this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/

Essentially before VPC endpoints were introduced the only way to access certain AWS services was using a public URL, this is fine unless you are working in a locked down VPC where an instance might not have access to the public internet. With the introduction of VPC endpoints a few days ago you can now access AWS service(s) directly from a private instance.

As of right now S3 is the only one supported but no doubt it will be rolled out to similar services, e.g. DynamoDB, SQS, SNS, etc in the near future.

The exception to this is services that are able to live inside a VPC that you create, i.e. when creating them you tell them which VPC, and often subnet as well where they should be created. Examples of this are ELB, RDS, EC2, Redshift, etc. For these there is no need to create an endpoint, they already exist in your VPC and can be accessed directly.